# Targeting specific div to update image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a simple piece of JS to change the image that is in a div from plus to minus. I have multiple divs on this page which are generated dynamically. How could I specifically change the sign on the div that is clicked. Currently I have the same class for each div. This means whenever I click any div only the first divs image changes, not the div that was clicked.

```
<div class="hover2 opacity" onclick="changeImage()">
     <h3><a>Test</a></h3>

    <div class="layer1">
        <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage"  src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
            <br>more</p>
        <div class="content">hello</div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="hover2 opacity" onclick="changeImage()">
     <h3><a>Test</a></h3>

    <div class="layer1">
        <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage"  src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
            <br>more</p>
        <div class="content">hello</div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

JS

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("plus")) {
        image.src = "img/minus.svg";
    } else {
        image.src = "img/plus.svg";
    }
}
```

Is the only way to fix this dynamically assigning new class to each div and generating multiple scripts for teach class?

EDIT:

I am using the same method as before but on a slightly different layout. Any reason why this isnt working?

```
<div class="open-link" style="display: block;">
     <a href="#" class="img-change">
         <p class="inner">Expand <br><img id="myImage"  src="img/arrow-down.svg" width="20" height="20"></p>
     </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','a.img-change',function(){
    var $img = $(this).find('p.inner');
    if($img.attr('src').match("down"))
        $img.attr('src','img/arrow-up.svg');
    else
        $img.attr('src','img/arrow-down.svg')
});
```

Comment: See if this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/anga07rv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `img` in your markup has the same id, this is bad, all elements, if they have an id, should be unique. This does NOT mean you should use a unique id on every image and a specific script for every button! That would be bad. Just remove the duplicate id's!

Then this is pretty easy, use jQuery to attach a click event to every `div` and look for the image within it

take off the in-line `onclick`

```
<div class="hover2 opacity">
```

and use jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','div.hover2',function(){
    var $img = $(this).find('p.heading img');
    if($img.attr('src').match("plus"))
        $img.attr('src','img/minus.svg');
    else
        $img.attr('src','img/plus.svg')
});
```

Comment: PERFECT! I don't know why I didn't use jQuery in the first place!

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at the edit i just made.

Comment: @john `var $img = $(this).find('p.inner');`  is finding the `p` element not the image. It will almost certainly work with `var $img = $(this).find('p.inner img');`

Comment: will give that a go. also i just noticed with the example you gave me the sign changes when i click on the collapsed content, when it should not. Should i target a different div to click on?

Comment: Ok, looks like i fixed that. Just wrapped the heading and p elements in a div and am selecting that div in the script. The solution you gave me for my edit didnt work. it didnt change the image. I will keep trying to find a fix!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign an id to the `<img/>` elements

HTML

```
<div class="hover2 opacity" onclick="changeImage(this)">
    <h3><a>Test</a></h3>
    <div class="layer1">
        <p class="heading">view 
            <span class="s-right">
                <img src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20">
            </span>
            <br>more</p>
        <div class="content">hello</div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

JS

```
function changeImage(el){
    var img = el.querySelector('span > img');
    img.src = (img.src.match("plus")) ? "img/minus.svg" : "img/plus.svg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".opacity").on("click", function() {

    var source = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); // Gives source of image inside the presently clicked div
    console.log(source);
    if (source.match("plus")) {
      console.log("match");
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "img/minus.svg");
    } else {
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "img/plus.svg");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover2 opacity">
  <h3><a>Test</a></h3>

  <div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage"  src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
      <br>more</p>
    <div class="content">hello</div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="hover2 opacity">
  <h3><a>Test</a></h3>

  <div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage"  src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
      <br>more</p>
    <div class="content">hello</div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

U still can use `$(this).find('img')` to find img for selected div and change the src.

Example

```
<div class="layer1">
        <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage1" class="myImage" src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
            <br>more</p>
        <div class="content">hello</div>
    </div>

<div class="layer1">
        <p class="heading">view <span class="s-right"><img id="myImage2" class="myImage" src="img/plus.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
            <br>more</p>
        <div class="content">hello</div>
    </div>
```

So it your javascript, u can use this

```
$(document).on('click','div.hover2',function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src","img/minus.svg");
}
```

Jsfiddle link -> https://jsfiddle.net/w1yb5fcc/1/

Comment: This will do exactly the same as the example posted by John. The only difference is the usage of jQuery instead of vanilla JS.

Comment: The way is a different one, but the result will be the same. You're selecting the first element with class `myImage` regardless of the clicked div. It will always be the first element in the DOM with the class `myImage` -> the same result as calling `document.getElementById` with a duplicated Id.

Comment: i just create a jsfiddle and update my answer. its proof the result was different. u may refer the link here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1yb5fcc/)

Comment: Did you test it yourself? I don't think so... Just open the console and click the right image.